# The value of $\operatorname{trace}(V^TBV)$ is accordance with the number of columns of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

The matrix $B_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is symmetric whose diagonalization is given by:

$$B = Q \Lambda Q$$ Also, given that $V_{n\times p}(\mathbb{R})$ whose columns are the vectors $v_i$ we may have:

$$\operatorname{tr}(V^TBV) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i\sum_{j=1}^{p}\tilde{v}_{ij}^2$$ where $\tilde{v}_{ij} = Q^Tv_i$ and $\lambda_i$ are the diagonal entries of $\Lambda$.

So my question is if you could help to prove:

> Assume that $B_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is a positive semi-definite and let $p$ be the number of columns of $V$. If $B$ has at most $p-1$ zero eigenvalues then $\operatorname{tr}(V^TBV)$ is non-zero for any $V$ where $V$ has orthonormal columns.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that Q is orthogonal, $Q^Tv_1, Q^Tv_2,...,Q^Tv_p$ are orthonormal. Suppose that $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k$ are zero eigenvalues of B and $k\leq p-1$, while $$\operatorname{tr}(V^TBV) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_i\sum_{j=1}^{p}\tilde{v}_{ij}^2=0$$

Then we have 
$$\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}\lambda_i\sum_{j=1}^{p}\tilde{v}_{ij}^2=0$$

Thus $\tilde{v}_{ij}=0$ for $i=k+1,k+2,...,n$ and $j=1,2,...,n$.

Now $Q^TV$ becomes a matrix with $n-k$ zero rows. So $rank(Q^TV)\leq k \leq p-1$. But the columns of $Q^TV$ are orthonormal, so the 1 to p rows and 1 to p columns of $Q^TV$ consist of an orthonormal matrix $\hat{V}$. But $rank(\hat{V})=p$, so that $rank(Q^TV)\geq p$, which contradicts to our assumption above. Thus, $\operatorname{tr}(V^TBV)$ is non-zero.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I have understand most of it. The only thing I didn't catch 100% is the part about $\hat{V}$. 

`1.`Do you suppose that $\hat{V}$ is a submatrix of $Q^TVQ$?
`2.` I see that telling $rank(Q^TV) \ge p$ is more beautiful to contradict $rank(Q^TV) \le k \le p-1$ but wouldn't be enough to say that $rank(Q^TV) = p$ (because of orthonormal columns) and make a contradiction?

Comment: Well, $\hat{v}$ is a submatrix of $Q^TV$. And you can also say that $rank(Q^TV)=p$ if $rank(\hat{v})=p$

Comment: Do you mean $\hat{V}$ instead of $\hat{v}$?

Comment: Yes...sorry for the spelling mistake